# Copy files from the same subdirectory to the same Directory in Windows

Tags: windows, powershell, directory, robocopy

I am having a hard time describing the problem and I can't find the solution anywhere so here is an example

```
SourceFolder\ProjectA\Legal\ContractA.txt
SourceFolder\ProjectB\Legal\ContractB.txt
SourceFolder\ProjectC\Legal\ContractC.txt
SourceFolder\ProjectD\Legal\ContractD.txt
etc..
```

I need to copy the contract*letter*.txt file from hundreds of these Project*letter* folders to a single location such as this:

```
DestinationFolder\ContractA.txt
DestinationFolder\ContractB.txt
DestinationFolder\ContractC.txt
DestinationFolder\ContractD.txt
etc..
```

Is there a PowerShell command that will do it?

Comment: `gci SourceFolder\Contract* -rec | % {copy-item $_ -destination "DestinationFolder\$($_.name)"}` might do but you would overwrite identical filenames

Comment: I think this would be ok if the path up to the Contract.txt files would be the same but the Project folder names are all different

Comment: If the filenames are all different, the oneliner could suffice. Add a `-whatif` just before the `}` to do a dry run.

Comment: It's not just the files that are different it is also the folder before, the ProjectA,B,C and D folders

Comment: Did you try it? (*with* the -whatif parameter!)

Comment: Great, that did it, thanks for your help